# Remove duplicate values from strings

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I have two strings

```
string s1 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry";
string s2 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry, Pear";
```

Now I want to compare both strings and remove duplicate values and
result should be

```
string s3 = "Pear"
```

How to do it?

I have tried:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> {CommonJurisdictions };
List<string> list2 = new List<string> { Jurisdiction };
List<string> ulist = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

but it doesn't give expected result.

Comment: Those are not strings but something that doesn't compile. Provide real code and show what you've tried.

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ to solve your problem? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your first and second code examples does not _even_ match. One is for `string` and the other is for `List<string>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.Split`, `Enumerable.Except`, `Concat` and `String.Join`

```
string s1 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry";
string s2 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry, Pear";

var s1Token = s1.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToArray();
var s2Token = s2.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToArray();
var inSecondNotFirst = s1Token.Except(s2Token);
var inFirstNotSecond = s2Token.Except(s1Token);
string s3 = String.Join(", ", inSecondNotFirst.Concat(inFirstNotSecond));
```

But more efficient (`O(n)`) would be to use a `HashSet<T>` and it's  [`SymmetricExceptWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
 var s1Token = new HashSet<string>(s1.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()));
 var s2Token = new HashSet<string>(s2.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()));
 s1Token.SymmetricExceptWith(s2Token);
 string s3 = String.Join(", ", s1Token);
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are List of strings use `Except`:

```
List<string> s1 = new List<string> {"Apple", "Mango","Cherry"};
List<string> s2 = new List<string> {"Apple", "Mango", "Cherry", "Pear"};
var result = s2.Except(s1); //Pear
```

Or if they are just string this should get your favorite result:

```
string s1 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry";
string s2 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry, Pear";
string result = s2.Replace(s1 + ',', "");// Pear
```

Comment: Oops, 8,6k and still with an uncustomized nickname? :\

Answer (score 0):

```
string s1 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry";
string s2 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry, Pear";

var a1 = s1.Split(',');
var a2 = s2.Split(',');

var result = string.Join(", ", a2.Except(a1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var array1 = s1.Split(',');
var array2 = s2.Split(',');


var s= array1.Except(array2).Concat(array2.Except(array1));
```

this will find unique from both the array

Answer (score 0):

And yet another one (*based on OP's example*):

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "Apple", "Mango", "Cherry", "Strawberry" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "Apple", "Mango", "Cherry", "Pear" }; 

var ulist = list1.Except(list2).Union(list2.Except(list1)).ToList();
```

Comment: You can use `Concat` since `Except` has already removed duplicates. Concat simply appends whereas Union skips duplicates, so it's more work.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good hint, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the SymmetricExceptWith method of the HashSet class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var seperator = ", ".ToCharArray();

string s1 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry";
string s2 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry, Pear";

string[] a1 = s1.Split(seperator);
string[] a2 = s2.Split(seperator);

var difference = new HashSet<string>(a1);
difference.SymmetricExceptWith(a2);
```

You could easily refactor this to remove the additional assignments.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s1 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry";

string s2 = "Apple, Mango, Cherry, Pear";

List<string> list1 = s1.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
List<string> list2 = s2.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();

var res = list2.Count > list1.Count ? list2.Where(s => !list1.Contains(s)).ToList() :
                                      list1.Where(s => !list2.Contains(s)).ToList();
```